# Get the 'YESTERDAY DATE' - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

```
 Dim tingin As Date = DateAndTime.DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, DateAndTime.Now)
 Dim trimmoto As String = Trim(tingin)
 MsgBox(trimmoto)
```

**I want to get the 'DATE ONLY'**

[image]

Comment: `Dim x as Date`, `x = Now()`, `x = x -1`, `Msgbox(x)`. Dates are number of days since ancient history. The fraction is the time. All dates include time. What you see is how to choose to format it with `FormatDateTime`, it still contains the time even if you don't show it. So `Round(x, 0)` will round it to whole days but the time will be 12 am.

Comment: how I should -1 the date only ?

Comment: As I explained there is no such thing as date only. You use `FormatDateTime` to format it how you want. values to the left of the decimal represent date information while - *... values to the right of the decimal represent time. Midnight is 0 and midday is 0.5. Negative whole numbers represent dates before 30 December 1899.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add :-

```
 Dim tingin As Date = DateAndTime.DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, DateAndTime.Now)
    Dim trimmoto As String = tingin.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
    MsgBox(trimmoto)
```

Or :-

```
Dim tingin As Date = Now.AddDays(-1)
    Dim trimmoto As String = tingin.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
    MsgBox(trimmoto)
```

Comment: It's not working :(

Comment: sorry just have a look at my Edit ! !

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has been already answered.

I just want to emphasize the use of depreciated VB Functions.
Do not use the TRIM() command anymore as this is already depreciated.
This dates back to VB6 and Classic VBSCRIPT.

It is just there for backward compatibility.

Use the .NET counterpart .TOSTRING.TRIM

Same goes with FORMAT(NumberVariable,"yyyy-dd-MM").
Use .TOSTRING.FORMAT(NumberVariable,"yyyy-dd-MM") instead.